# Javascript regex -- removing letters BEFORE a capital letter and replacing _ with a space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of strings that I am iterating through. Some of them are

```
data-Start, data-End_Start, Name, ID, data-Allocate_Memory
```

I need them in this format

```
Start,End Start, Name, ID, Allocate Memory
```

So I need to remove the "data-" and then replace the _ with a space. I am clueless when it comes to regexp. Any help would be nice :)

Comment: if it will always be in this form, you can just `var result = string.replace("data-", "").replace("_"," ");`

Comment: I agree with @Shmiddty - you don't need a regex for this (based on what's posted)

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://www.WhatHaveYouTried.com)

Comment: replace() only replaces the first instance, unless you use the `g` option on regex.  i.e it should be `replace(/data-/g, '')`

Comment: @broofa - That's the problem with poorly asked questions like these. He doesn't really say if he needs multiple occurrences replaced, so we just have to guess.

Comment: @lwburk - "I need them is this format [all 'data-' strings removed here]" seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start your string at the first uppercase letter, you can use:

```
str = str.replace(/^[^A-Z]+/,'');
```

To replace `_` with space, just use:

```
str = str.replace(/_/g,' ');
```

Since these two regexes can't be reasonably combined, you can chain them:

```
str = str.replace(/^[^A-Z]+/,'').replace(/_/g,' ');
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  `'data-Start, data-End_Start, Name, ID, data-Allocate_Memory'.replace(/^[^A-Z]+/,'').replace(/_/g,' ')
` => `Start, data-End Start, Name, ID, data-Allocate Memory`

Comment: I thought those strings were individually being processed. See edit.

Comment: @broofa - It seems you have misread the question and it is causing you to make unfair edits and downvotes. It clearly says in the question: *"I have a list of strings that I am iterating through"*

Comment: @lwburk The edit was fair, as I had missed the Shift key when typing a `(`. The dowvote, however, was not.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces occurrences of *data-* at the *start* of a string:

```
str.replace(/^data-/, "")
```

This replaces all underscores:

```
str.replace(/_/g, " ")
```

Putting it all together:

```
var a = ["data-Start", "data-End_Start", "Name", "ID", "data-Allocate_Memory"];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = a[i].replace(/^data-/, "").replace(/_/g, " ");
}
```

Comment: @broofa - I *intentionally* did not use the `g` flag. He doesn't explicitly say he wants *all* occurrences replaced (and all of his examples show *data-* at the beginning of the string). As I said above, he is not clear. If you think he's being clear, you're assuming too much. Obviously, it's OK to edit posts on SO, but you should be careful not to change the answerer's intended meaning.

Comment: @broofa - Additionally, your edit rendered my answer inconsistent because I say, *"This replaces occurrences of data- at the start of a string"*. I'm reverting.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I interpreted the question differently and thought your answer was closer to what the OP was after, subject to a couple minor edits.  (btw, you might change "the underscores" to read, "an underscore", as it's currently slightly misleading.)  As you said, the question isn't as clear as I'd thought at first.

Comment: @broofa - Good point on the underscores language. I actually left your `g` on that second one, since it isn't inconsistent with what he asked for (even though, again, the provided examples each have only one). So I'll just leave the language, as well.

Comment: your middle example still has `"_"`

Comment: @broofa - Good catch. I'll fix it.